# Sql and pattern matching

Tags: php, sql, regex

I have a field in table in which i have stored in database using serialize function Example

`a:3:{i:0;s:18:"Government Sectors";i:1;s:15:"Private Sectors";i:2;s:6:"Others";}`

Name of the SQL field is jobtype

Now I need to prepare a search based on this fields value My select statement is

`SELECT * FROM some_jobs  WHERE  jobtype='%$Keyword%' AND state=1`

Suppose the `$Keyword` value is government sectors

It's returning `NULL`. How do I go about this? Can I accomplish this using pattern matching in SQL, if yes then how?

Comment: can you demonstrate with an example as of my case?

Comment: Please provide a search term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to know the silly mistake i have done here!!

I have used = in the sql query instead of like term.

Modified the sql query to below code and it works.

```
SELECT * FROM some_jobs WHERE jobtype LIKE '%$Keyword%' AND state=1
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use the keyword LIKE
E.G.

```
SELECT * FROM some_jobs WHERE jobtype LIKE '%$Keyword%' AND state=1
```

The %'s are wildcards as you may know already.

LIKE is similar to REGEXP but is simpler to use and from what I read it preserve's the table index's so it queries faster.
This will return the row that contains that 'Keyword' somewhere inside the text.